# how to manipulate vertical position of legend key for multirows legend labels?

Tags: python, location, legend

i have a legend label with multiple rows. the default display of the corresponding legend key (so the marker from the plot) is centered next to the multiple rows. however, i want the legend key just centered infront of the first row of the label.

for a simple example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y1 = [2,2.4,3.1,3.7,4.5,5.3,5.4,6.1,6.2,6.4,7.3]
y2 = [1.5,2,3,4.6,5.1,5.4,6.3,6.5,5.2,5.5,4.2]

plt.plot(x,y1,label='single row label')
plt.plot(x,y2,label='multiple\nrow\nlabel')
plt.legend()
```

that gives the legend back as:

```
   multiple
-- row
   label
```

but I need:

```
-- multiple
   row
   label
```

i am a python-beginner so i tried looking it up, but i only found suggestions and examples about relocating the legend box or adjusting the lenght and distand of the handlebar to the text. but that did not help me.

Comment: How was `plt` defined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.